# Coaxial waveguide - wave impedance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, capacitance, inductance, waveguide

> Determine the capacity $C$ per $m$, the inductance $L$ per m and the wave impedance $Z_0$ for a coaxial waveguide with inner radius $a$ and outer radius $b$.
>
> How large would $b$ have to be so that for $a=1mm$$~~$ $Z_0=100\Omega$?

We talked about the wave impedance and waveguides on friday in my experimental physics lecture and the concept didn't really stuck in my head so I read the wiki entries about it, but it didn't really help me that much.

I was thinking of bluntly applying the formula to see where it would get me, even though I can't even find $C$ or $L$ before dealing with the wave impedance:

$Z=\frac{Z_0}{1-(\frac{f_c}{f})^2}$, that's the correct one, right?

So basically I have to find $f_c$ and $f$ since $Z_0$ is a fixed value?

But our teacher didn't talk about $f_c$ and $f$. I mean, thanks to wiki I know that it is the cut-off frequency but I don't know how to determine it. And wiki also differentiates between TE modes and TM modes, what's the difference?

Sorry for my lack of work but this topic just doesn't want to stick with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There 3 rather simple formulas which allow to compute the parameters that are asked for.

$L'=\mu/(2\pi) \cdot \ln(b/a)$ for the inductivity per meter L'

$C'=2\pi\epsilon/(\ln(b/a))$ for the capacity per meter C'

$Z= Z_0/2\pi \sqrt{\frac{\mu'}{\epsilon'}}\ln(b/a)$.

b is the outer diameter and a is the inner diameter of the coaxial line
$Z_0 = 376.73\Omega$, $\mu=\mu_0\mu'$ and $\epsilon=\epsilon_0\epsilon'$
For a line without filling $\mu'=1$ and $\epsilon'=1$. 
I think, this answers the question.

Comment: Where did you get those formulas? I was googling some suitable formulas for the problem, but couldn't find any.

Comment: I got it from the proceedings of the RF-engineering for particle accelerators, CAS (Cern Accelerator School). Nevertheless, I would expect them in every textbook on electrotechnical engineering.